# Mongo Query to fetch top 10 of the products who has max number of views per minute in last 7 days

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoengine, pymongo-3.x

Hello i am looking for a MongoDB Query. So below is the situation-

So i have two tables First is Pin and second is mostLovedPins. below is the collection structure.

> Pin Model

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6149a35962711bd3ccba758d"
    },
    "_cls": "PinModel",
    "created_at": {
        "$date": "2021-09-21T09:12:18.974Z"
    },
    "updated_at": {
        "$date": "2021-09-21T09:12:18.974Z"
    },
    "store": "612de0ff161c359e0e15ea7b",
    "type": "CATALOG_PIN",
    "offer_type": "LAST_MINUTE_OFFER",
    "title": "Iphone 18",
    "description": "Food is good",
    "schedule_type": "IMMEDIATE",
    "schedule_days": ["SUNDAY", "MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY"],
    "discount_unit": "PERCENT",
    "latlong": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [81.4471435546875, 23.61432859499169]
    },
    "address": "",
    "city": "",
    "country": "",
    "pin": "",
    "payment_type": "INSTORE",
    "meta_info": {},
    "is_published": true,
    "is_approved_by_admin": true
}
```

> MostLovedPins Collection

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "615563fde3c22a2cf6e3c500"
    },
    "_cls": "MostLovedPins",
    "created_at": {
        "$date": "2021-09-30T06:56:09.162Z"
    },
    "updated_at": {
        "$date": "2021-09-30T06:56:09.162Z"
    },
    "pin": {
        "$oid": "6153feebf14b15db64dfaef5"
    },
    "view_count": 3,
    "date": {
        "$date": "2021-09-30T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "users": []
}
```

I have stored view count and date. For example i have 50 views on a product today. So i need a query to satisfy below conditions:

1. Get last 7 days view count in a radius near a particular lat long, and add them.
2. Take top 10 of the products who has max number of views per minute in last 7 days.

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.